# error: could not read db 'multilib' (Can't parse line 1)

Tags: upgrade, manjaro, pacman

When I run the command,

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

I get a lot of errors like this:

```
error: could not read db 'core' (Can't parse line 1)
error: could not read db 'multilib' (Can't parse line 1)
```

And then at the end of it, says:

```
there is nothing to do
```

[image: sudo pacman -Syu]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just received a similar error message, for me it occurred because I tried to run an update earlier in a network that required me to login. 
So somehow the HTML login page landed in my sync files for core, community, multilib here:
`/var/lib/pacman/sync/community.db`

Simply check if a similar thing happened to you:

`$ cat /lib/pacman/sync/core.db`

For me, simply removing these files was sufficient to fix the `pacman` issues. 
If you're unsure copy them to a safe location prior to that. 

`$ sudo cp /lib/pacman/sync/core.db ~
$ sudo cp /lib/pacman/sync/multilib.db ~
$ ...`

I guess there is also a pacman command for clearing the cache wich should work aswell.

Comment: Removing `/var/lib/pacman/sync/community.db` and the same file for `multilib.db` and `core.db` and then running `sudo pacman-key --populate` fixed it.